# Convert sql query with a join on a subselect to a linq statement

Tags: mysql, linq

I am trying to convert the following sql query to LINQ statement

```
SELECT t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT Unique_Id, MAX(Version) mversion
        FROM    test
        GROUP BY Unique_Id
    ) m INNER JOIN
    test t  ON m.Unique_Id = t.Unique_Id AND m.mversion = t.Version
```

LINQ statement

```
var testalt = (from altt in CS.test
group altt by altt.Unique_Id into g
join bp in CS.alerts on g.FirstOrDefault().Unique_Id equals bp.Unique_Id
select new ABCBE
{
ABCName= bp.Name,
number = bp.Number,
Unique_Id =  g.Key,
Version = g.Max(x=>x.Version)
});
```

I am getting an error of where clause. Please help

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a737/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy straight forward conversion but you can accomplish the same thing using linq method syntax.  The first query is executed to an expression tree, then you are joining that expression tree from the grouping against CS.alerts.  This combines the expression tree from CS.test query into the expression tree of CS.alerts to join the two expression trees.

The expression tree is evaluated to build the query and execute said query upon enumeration.  Enumeration in this case is the ToList() call but anything that gets a result from the enumeration will execute the query.

```
var query1 = CS.test.GroupBy(x => x.Unique_Id);
var joinResult = CS.alerts.Join(query1, 
   alert => new { ID = alert.Unique_Id, Version = alert.Version },
   test => new { ID = test.Key, Version = test.Max(y => y.Version }, 
   (alert, test) => new ABCBE { 
      ABCName = alert.Name, 
      number = alert.Number, 
      Unique_Id = test.Key, 
      Version = test.Max(y => y.Version)
    }).ToList();
```

Because query1 is still an IQueryable and you are using CS.alerts (which I'm guessing CS is your data context) it should join and build the query to execute upon the ToList() enumeration.

Comment: I am getting error for line  

test.Values.Max(y => y.Version 

Values is not an extension method

Comment: Sorry... Syntax snafu.  You do not need values, I corrected the answer to reflect what is needed.  It would be test.Max(y => y.Version)

Comment: :: I am still not getting the right result. I am not getting the latest records by version. Please can you just have a look at the SQL fiddle in the question. So that you will have exact idea what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You are joining on two columns, thus you need to change the selector to match.  alert => new {... } and test => new { ... }  this is the joining condition.  You can alter this as needed to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: In case you missed it, I altered the answer to reflect your SQL Fiddle.